# Difference between Parallel copy garbage collector and Parallel Scavenge garbage collector

Tags: garbage-collection

Recently, I was looking into Java Hotspot Garbage Collector. Searching on this topic I found that most of sources uses two terms called "Parallel Scavenge Collector" and "Parallel Copy collector" (Like [oraclecollectors](http://www.fasterj.com/articles/oraclecollectors1.shtml)).
I am confused what is the difference between two. As far as I know both are same. I know about copy collect where it moves live objects from "from" to "to" space. If there is difference between two collector, please provide me the detail about it. And if No, there why it uses term "Scavenge" instead of "copy" ?

Answer (score 1):

They are different implementations of more or less the same concept.

As the page you linked already says itself, they are meant to cooperate with different old gen collectors which have different needs for cross-generation marking.

Some of the currently possibly GC combinations in hotspot have already [been deprecated](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/173) in jdk8 and [will be removed](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/214) in jdk9

Quote from an old hotspot FAQ:

> In addition the parallel young generation collector (-XX:+UseParNewGC)
>   is integrated with the concurrent low pause collector whereas the
>   parallel garbage collector (-XX:+UseParallelGC) is not. There are some
>   costs associated with this integration which are borne even when the
>   concurrent low pause collector is not used. Conversely the parallel
>   garbage collector (-XX:+UseParallelGC) can be used with adaptive
>   sizing (-XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy) whereas the parallel young
>   generation collector (-XX:+UseParNewGC) cannot.

You can find some additional details on [this blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/our_collectors)

If that's still not enough information for you I recommend hitting the hotspot-gc-dev mail archives, which might have some implementation details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had the suspicion from [page](http://www.fasterj.com/articles/oraclecollectors1.shtml) i linked that is some difference but I could not find any source that talk about the differences between. Can you please provide me the detail that implementation wise is the difference between two?